# iPhone LINE-IN audio recording Possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio-recording

Can we record audio from direct line-in input with iPhone?

Comment: Hm, looked all round my iPhone again and couldn't find an appropriate jack for audio input, or do you plan a socket connector adaption?

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to create your own accessory using the dock connector and then to use the API's provided!